# How to export svg from pixijs

Tags: javascript, svg, pixi.js, drawing2d

Is it possible to render svg from pixie composition?
I'm working on a project where I'll draw generative graphics and then I'll have to have them in some vector format because this will go to print.
I would be happy to get svg or some other vector format.

The reason I'm doing this with pixie is that I will later use that compositions as animations on a company website.

Comment: As others said, it's almost impossible to go from rasterized graphics to SVG. It's extremely easy to go from SVG to rasterized though. So maybe you can restructure your project to use SVG from the start, and rasterize assets for your site, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can draw and render SVG data using the [pixi-svg-graphics](https://github.com/saschagehlich/pixi-svg-graphics) module, but I am pretty sure that you can't export any vector format. That's because pixi.js uses rasterized textures internally, not vector data.

Answer (score 0):

That's not gonna happen pixi is raster based, even above plugin as noted above will only draw vectors on top of raster images.

If you want I can redraw any raster images into vector images, it's not that much work :P